# How to introduce boost::shared_ptr into an existing (large) C++ codebase?

Tags: c++, boost, refactoring, shared-ptr

I am currently trying to fix a few weaknesses in our code base by introducing the use of smart pointers. The code base is very large, and interlinked like a spider who's had one to many coffee's.

I was wondering if people had tried the before and what their approach was.

My first step has been to typedef classes, as follows.

```
#ifndef USE_SMART_POINTERS
    #define USE_SMART_POINTERS 0
#endif

#if USE_SMART_POINTERS == 1
    #include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#endif


namespace ProductX
{
    // forward decleration
    class CTObject;


    //typedefs
    #if USE_SMART_POINTERS == 1
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<CTObject> CTObjectPtr;
    #else
        typedef CTObject* CObjectPtr;
    #endif
}
```

Now I realise this will lead to a wealth of compile areas, things like

```
CTObjectPtr i = NULL;
```

Will completly bork when smart pointers are enabled.

I was wondering if there was anything I could do at this early stage to reduce the mass of compile errors, or is it as I suspect just take things on a case by case basis.

Cheers
Rich

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do this: the typedefs I mean.

Presumably the old code has at least some **delete** calls in it?  Which would certainly fail in the case of a smart pointer.

Smart pointer certain things or not, i.e. chase a specific instance through the code base.  Make it work, then move on.  Good Luck!

Comment: Looking at the wealth of code I'm starting to think you're right. Thank you for stopping me going on a crazy code cull.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to introduce smart pointers everywhere you could use the [Boehm-Demers-Weiser](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) garbage collector and leave your code base intact.

It will also take care of cyclic references.

Comment: +1: it is important the remark about cyclic references. That is something that must be taken care of if using smart pointers (using `weak_ptr` to break cycles)

Comment: An important point about the Boehm collecter is that it's conservative -- it's not guaranteed to clean up all garbage.  Nor is it deterministic, like all non-reference counted collectors.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to do this. As you've found out, `boost::shared_ptr`s and standard pointers are not interchangeable. What you are doing here is refactoring code, and unfortunately refactoring takes a long time and can be very tedious.

As sdg said, `typedef`ing pointers for `shared_ptr`s is not a good idea, and just increases the amount of code you have to write.

First, I would identify the pointers that actually need to be changed to `shared_ptr`s. Obviously you don't want to be changing all pointers to `shared_ptr`s. Most would probably be better off as `std::auto_ptr`s or `boost::scoped_ptr`s and some would be better as `boost::weak_ptr`, and finally some might just be fine as plain C-style pointers.

Just go through each pointer that needs changing one-by-one, find all references to it, and make the necessary adjustments (e.g. removing calls to `delete`).

Comment: Probably the easiest way to start such a conversion (if you're sure a particular type should always be either a `shared_ptr` or a `weak_ptr`) is to use the self-factory pattern -- make a static shared_ptr<X> X::create(...) method, and change the constructor to private or protected.  Now fix all the compiler errors.  Only do one type at a time!  (Well, you might need to do derived classes at the same time.)

Answer (score 0):

I would be very restrictive in introducing shared_ptr into an existing large codebase. If you really want to use smart-pointers to fix errors I suggest using scoped pointers and other than that I would refactor code and design clear ownership.